# How to make and visualize connections between survey participants using programming language (preferably R, Python or DAX)?

Tags: python, r, powerbi, connection, visualization

I have the dataset from survey with participants IDs and IDs of another participant (or participants) that first participant knows, just like this:

| Participant ID | Knows participant |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 353 |
| 111 | **777** |
| 111 | **112** |
| 111 | 249 |
| 112 | 143 |
| 112 | 144 |
| 113 | **111** |
| 113 | 244 |
| 114 | NaN |
| 115 | **113** |
| ... | ... |
| 777 | **111** |
| 777 | 398 |
| 777 | **114** |
| 778 | NaN |
| 779 | **112** |
| 3499 | NaN |

As you can see, some participants do not know any other participants (but it does not mean, that other participant also does not know him/her), however, some participants know 1, 2, 3 or even more other participants (and again some participants might does not not her/him ans vise versa).

So is it possible to build and visualize all possible connections between each participant (personal acquaintance, acquaintance through another participant and so on)?

Comment: I am not particularly sure but the first thing that comes to mind is a markov chain. Where each node is a participant and the path to each node is defined by the who knows who.

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you are looking for suggestions for data visualization or statistical modeling, those questions are a better fit for [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a simple chord diagram to show these connections. Chord diagrams can be created in PBI, Python or R.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've also find info about "Network chart", also will be useful to build connections between data. And it's pretty simple to build using Power BI :)